# How to get runtime types in polkadotjs (typescript)

Tags: polkadot-js, metadata, typescript

In subxt we can have Rust types directly from scale-encoded runtime metadata. Is the same possible in polkadotjs? Is there a "polkadots" which has typescript types automatically derived from runtime metadata?

- doc https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.create